# .net Web App - lite weight Reporting Engine and Report Manager options

Tags: .net, reporting-services

We are looking for a alternative option to SSRS Reporting Manager which we can imbed in our web application. http://www.plutora.com

We have looked at SSRS, Active Reports, Crystal and Telerik and none of them are actually user-friendly and lite weight enough where end users can build there own reports without training.

We use sencha front end controls, SQL Sever 2008 and .net 4 (RAZR)

Any good, stable Reporting Manager options out there as alternatives? User should have ability to execute existing reports, Change parameters to existing reports, build own custom reports, apply public and private permissions and off-course do basic formatting to each report.

Answer (score 0):

You can try our [SharpShooter Reports](http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/SharpShooter-Reports-Enterprise.aspx). It support several technologies: Win Forms, WPF, Silverlight, WinRT. Also we have pure [JavaScript and HTML web viewer](http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/Demo/SSReports.Web/Web/StartPage.htm) which can be used in any .NET based web systems.

Reports support a high-flexible parameters as you need.

The system also have Windows-based designer allowing the user to create his/her own reports.